# Algorithm to generate a (pseudo-) random high-dimensional function

Tags: algorithm, random

**I don't mean a function that generates random numbers, but an algorithm to generate a [random function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_function)**

"High dimension" means the function is multi-variable, e.g. a 100-dim function has 100 different variables.

Let's say the domain is [0,1], we need to generate a function f:[0,1]^n->[0,1]. This function is chosen from a certain class of functions, so that the probability of choosing any of these functions is the same. 
(This class of functions can be either all continuous, or K-order derivative, whichever is convenient for the algorithm.)

Since the functions on a closed interval domain are uncountable infinite, we only require the algorithm to be pseudo-random.

Is there a polynomial time algorithm to solve this problem?

---

I just want to add a possible algorithm to the question(but not feasible due to its exponential time complexity). The algorithm was proposed by the friend who actually brought up this question in the first place:

The algorithm can be simply described as following. First, we assume the dimension d = 1 for example. Consider smooth functions on the interval I = [a; b]. First, we split the domain [a; b] into N small intervals. For each interval Ii, we generate a random number fi living in some specific distributions (Gaussian or uniform distribution). Finally, we do the interpolation of
series (ai; fi), where ai is a characteristic point of Ii (eg, we can choose ai as the middle point of Ii). After interpolation, we gain a smooth curve, which can be regarded as a one dimensional random function construction living in the function space Cm[a; b] (where m depends on the interpolation algorithm we choose).

This is just to say that the algorithm does not need to be that formal and rigorous, but simply to provide something that works.

Comment: you will probably need to specify the `certain class of functions` more precisely. While it is quite easy to generate random coefficients for polynomial functions (with a fixed degree), you will have a hard time finding a suitable basis for the vectorspace of all continuous functions which allows for something similar. Just imagine abs(x), sin(x) or exp(x) as simple examples for functions which you would like to include in your random-function-generator, but which you won't be able to generate by "randomly" picking some values.

Comment: @HW My question is to generate ANY continuous or K-order derivative functions on a closed interval, not a simple type of function. And this is indeed what makes the problem hard....

Comment: For the phrase "the probability of choosing any of these functions is the same" to be meaningful requires that **you** choose the "certain class of functions" and a measure on that class of functions. Otherwise, if **I** get to choose, I just choose the class of linear functions satisfying the conditions, then I choose an algorithm for selecting them, then I define the measure of a subset of functions to be equal to the probability that my selection is in that subset, so my selection algorithm is automatically uniform with respect to my measure.

Comment: `This is just to say that the algorithm does not need to be that formal and rigorous, but simply to provide something that works.` The problem with that is that you stated that you want to be able to generate any continuous function! By simply connecting some dots you will of course obtain a continuous function and with increasing the number of dots you can get quite close to any desired function. However by "randomly" choosing these dots you will most likely obtain functions that oscillate quite heavily, so this is far from an approach that answers your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

So if i get it right you need function returning scalar from vector;

**The easiest way I see is the use of dot product**

- for example let `n` be the dimensionality you need
- so create random vector `a[n]` containing random coefficients in range `<0,1>`
- and the sum of all coefficients is 1

  1. create `float a[n]`
  2. feed it with positive random numbers (no zeros)
  3. compute the sum of `a[i]`
  4. divide `a[n]` by this sum
- now the function `y=f(x[n])` is simply
- `y=dot(a[n],x[n])=a[0]*x[0]+a[1]*x[1]+...+a[n-1]*x[n-1]`
- if I didn't miss something the target range should be `<0,1>`
- if `x==(0,0,0,..0)` then `y=0;`
- if `x==(1,1,1,..1)` then `y=1;`

**If you need something more complex use higher order of polynomial**

- something like `y=dot(a0[n],x[n])*dot(a1[n],x[n]^2)*dot(a2[n],x[n]^3)...`
- where `x[n]^2` means `(x[0]*x[0],x[1]*x[1],...)`

**Booth approaches results in function with the same "direction"**

- if any `x[i]` rises then `y` rises too
- if you want to change that then you have to allow also negative values for `a[]`
- but to make that work you need to add some offset to `y` shifting from negative values ...
- and the `a[]` normalization process will be a bit more complex
- because you need to seek the min,max values ...
- **easier option** is to add random flag vector `m[n]` to process
- `m[i]` will flag if `1-x[i]` should be used instead of `x[i]`
- this way all above stays as is ...
- you can create more types of mapping to make it even more vaiable

Answer (score 0):

This might not only be hard, but impossible if you actually want to be able to generate every continuous function.

For the one-dimensional case you might be able to create a useful approximation by looking into the [Faber-Schauder-System](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Faber-Schauder_system) (also see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis)). This gives you a Schauder-basis for continuous functions on an interval. This kind of basis only covers the whole vectorspace if you include infinite linear combinations of basisvectors. Thus you can create some random functions by building random linear combinations from this basis, but in general you won't be able to create functions that are actually represented by an infinite amount of basisvectors this way.

Edit in response to your update:

It seems like choosing a random polynomial function of order `K` (for the class of K-times differentiable functions) might be sufficient for you since any of these functions can be approximated (around a given point) by one of those (see [taylor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem)). Choosing a random polynomial function is easy, since you can just pick `K` random real numbers as coefficients for your polynom. (Note that this will for example  not return functions similar to abs(x))